# Lex : All ways meet error at Rules Section

Tags: lex

I started to use Lex for my homework. In my Lex file, I always meet errors when go to first line of Rules Section. I have tested on sample code in books.

Here is the errors that Flex throw :

> 1 Error: Parse error at line
>
> 2  Description: Badly formed macro definition.

And here is my code.

```
int num_lines = 0, num_chars = 0;
%%
\n ++num_lines; ++num_chars;     // error here 
. ++num_chars;
%%
main()
{
yylex();
printf( "# of lines = %d, # of chars = %d\n",
num_lines, num_chars );
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
%{
int num_lines = 0, num_chars = 0;
%}

%%
...
```

Comment: and I use JFlex. I don't know any differences with Lex ? (because `stackoverflow` doesn't have Flex for my work.